# merging arraying in d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

My `elex.csv` is in this format

```
"CONUM","PIXPMK","PIXMAR"

"1","461","436"
"2","398","428",
"3","447","436"
```

I want my dataset in this format-

```
var dataset1 = [ [1, 417], [1, 436], [2, 398], [2, 428], [3, 447], [3, 436]];
```

I have tried several times to get the fetch the data from csv in this form but all in vain. I am attaching my code

```
var dataset1 = [];

d3.csv("elex.csv", function(data) {
   dataset1 = data.map(function(d) { return [ [+d["CONUM"], +d["PIXMAR"]],[+d["CONUM"],+d["PIXPMK"]]]; });
console.log(dataset1)
});
```

this returns `dataset1` as

```
[[[1,417],[1,436]],[[2,398],[2,428]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each element, and push the first and second part into `dataset1` separately:

```
dataset1 = [];
d3.csv("elex.csv", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    dataset1.push([d['CONUM'], d['PIXMAR']]);
    dataset1.push([d['CONUM'], d['PIXPMK']*100])
  });
  console.log(dataset1);
});
```

Comment: Why the multiply by 100 ??

Comment: @thatOneGuy, it was the calculation OP used

Comment: could u please tell me the entire code...i tried this..but facing some problem

Comment: Realised i was looking at it wrong. Here's yours implemented in PLNKR : https://plnkr.co/edit/WerxLZgyLrr7PJt3YAYw?p=preview

Comment: thankz....it worked...the data is getting loaded..i can c through console....bt points are not getting plotted

Comment: @KuhuGupta, d3 helps you to bind data to the graphics you build. it's powerful that you can build any graphics you can imagine, but unlike other charting libraries, you have to do some extra work. [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) will get you started